# @Controller causing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-data

Why do I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest` when I add `@Controller` to `DummyController` class?

**it.cspnet.firstspringmvc.controller.Main**

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jpaContext.xml");
        Servizi servizi = ctx.getBean(Servizi.class);
        Utente utente = new Utente();
        utente.setUserName("test");
        utente.setPassword("test");
        Utente utenteInDb = servizi.login(utente);

        for (Ordine ordine : utenteInDb.getOrdini()) {
            System.out.println("ordine: " + ordine);
        }
    }
```

**it.cspnet.firstspringmvc.controller.DummyController**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
public class DummyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dummy", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String get(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "dummy";
    }
}
```

When I remove the `@Controller` annotation from **DummyController** then main prints out the `example`'s fine but if I put it back in then it throws:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

I'm using this project:

https://github.com/ivansaracino/spring-mvc-jparepository-example.git

All I've done is add **Main** and **DummyController**

Comment: what building system do you use ? maven ?

Comment: When adding `@Controller` the bean is detected and loaded, when removed it isn't loaded and when it isn't loaded the class `HttpServletRequest` isn't needed.

Comment: Because the dependcy is sopped provided. However it doesn't make sense to have a `@Controller` in a standalone program.

Comment: No it isn't as it tells you nothing for a web application, you should use your tests for that.

Comment: As stated you should use your tests for that... When including the servlet api (compile scope) you will run into problems with your server as you aren't allowed to include the servlet api in your application.

Comment: Then you have something very strange in your setup. What you do in your main class can quite easily be done in a test case. In which case you are also building your test suite at the same time instead of delaying that fact. Also judging from the name of the xml file, it is quite strange that that is also scanning for `@Controller`s judging from it it should only load other beans. I would expect it to setup a `DataSource`, `LocalContainerEntiytManagerFactory` and tx support but nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably missing right dependencies, like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please note that your version could be 2.5, 3.0 or 3.1 - it depends on application server you are using. Also when you want to create executable war you should probably not use provided scope (depending on your servlet container).

Comment: Sorry, I was offline. What is the status ? Works everything ? If not I would suggest you to use some of the spring boot manuals. You can find a lot of them on spring.io site. Althought it is tempting to try to configure all by yourself, the spring boot will save you a lot of time. Recently we migrated all of our old spring projects to spring boot and we will never go back.

Answer (score 1):

Your dependency scope is 'provided', so when you build the war this dependency won't be added to the class path! Make sure the dependency exists on App Server lib path.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```